# NSKeyedUnarchiver causing memory leak

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a memory leak problem, I'm saving an array into a file using:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:MyFile];
```

the objects included into the array have the following methods:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{

[super init];

parameter1 = [[coder decodeObject] retain];
parameter2 = [[coder decodeObject] retain];
parameter3 = [[coder decodeObject] retain];

return self;
 }

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
[coder encodeObject:parameter1];
[coder encodeObject:parameter2];
[coder encodeObject:parameter3];
}
```

To unarchive the objects I'm using:

```
myUnarchivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myFile];
```

The application suddenly crashes because the available memory is not enough to continue.

I'm unable to deallocate myUnarchivedArray and the Intruments tool is telling me that the unarchiver is causing the memory leak.

I haven't search too much, I just found the cause of the memory leak, but I was hopping to find someone that has been passed the same problem and has a tip to solve it.:)

Thank you!!
Anna

Comment: 32 bytes aprox, but the amount of them inside the array is variable.

Comment: Are the objects you're encoding/decoding custom types? If so, review their encode/decode methods.

Comment: nop, the object only have NSStrings as parameters

Comment: When it crashes, can you look at what the types are in the debugger? Or set a breakpoint in the encode method and check what exactly you're archiving? See if it's what you expect.

Comment: When I'm testing the application in the simulator and also in the iPhone before the memory warning is triggered, I'm able to use the objects I previously unarchived with no problems. The instruments is showing that the object that was not deallocated is: -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] but I'm not able to deallocate the result array from the unarchiving operation :(

Answer (score -1):

You're retaining your objects in *initWithCoder* although the documentation states:

*NSKeyedUnarchiver’s implementation, however, returns an autoreleased object, so its life is the same as the current autorelease pool instead of the keyed unarchiver.*

Comment: -1 The life of the object is the same as the current autorelease pool, *unless that object is retained*.  This is *standard* Objective-C memory management.

Comment: What makes you think this retain is balanced by a release?